# Access columns in a dynamic generated Material Table in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a dynamic material table in angular with the code

```
    <mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
  <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
              {{col | uppercase}}
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              {{element[col]}}
  </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  [ngClass]="row.SEQ % 4 == 0 ? 'rows' : 'row'"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

and my output looks like -

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to access rows named xyz to add a small button below the column name to do some function .

Something like this -

How can i access that ? Can anyone please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method #1 inline without a function**

```
  <mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{col | uppercase}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element[col]}}
        <mat-icon *ngIf="col === 'xyz' || col === 'abc'">YOUR_ICON_HERE</mat-icon>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  [ngClass]="row.SEQ % 4 == 0 ? 'rows' : 'row'"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

**Method #2 with a function**

***HTML FILE***

```
  <mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
      <mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>
        {{col | uppercase}}
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element[col]}}
        <mat-icon *ngIf="shouldDisplayIcon(col)">YOUR_ICON_HERE</mat-icon>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  [ngClass]="row.SEQ % 4 == 0 ? 'rows' : 'row'"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

***TS FILE***

```
shouldDisplayIcon(name: string): boolean {
  if (name === 'xyz' || name === 'abc'){
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

The Function way will give you more advantages if this function will have to grow in the future and if you decide to convert the  into an array or enum you can check using a .includes or other property instead of hardcoded but since I can only see this code I had to hardcode it.

If you want to use icon here is their docs on all the icons they have https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

Comment: Thank you for the help , Do u have any idea how to change the class of a particular column ? Like if i want to change the width of a column , how could i achieve that ?

Comment: if your doing it dynamiclly? look into ng-class